# php file_get_contents or curl not working

Tags: php, curl

I want to get data from bseindia.com by using curl but I am getting only null as data..

here's my curl function code:

```
    <?php 
    function load($url, $ispost=0, $data='', $header=array()){
        if($url=='' || ($ispost && $data=='')) return;

        $host=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

        $header[]='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0';
        $header[]='Host: '.$host;
        $header[]='Connection: keep-alive';
        $header[]='Referer: http://'.$host.'/';
        if($ispost) $header[]='Content-length: '.strlen($data);

        $ch = curl_init("$url");
        if($ispost){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        $file = curl_exec($ch);
        $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return array('http_code'=>$header['http_code'], 'output'=>$file);
}
    ?>
```

and here's my calling:

```
<?php
    $data = load('http://www.bseindia.com/', 0, '');
    if($data['http_code']!==200) exit(json_encode(array('err'=>true, 'msg'=>'Unable to get! Error='.$data['http_code'])));
    exit(json_encode(array('err'=>false, 'msg'=>json_decode($data['output']))));
?>
```

but my output in json is:

```
{"err":false,"msg":null}
```

but if I change

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
```

then I am getting the output directly printed but not stored in variable, why??

So, my question is how do I get data without using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
```

???

Comment: Is it possible it's related to the fact that you are turning off headers (`CURLOPT_HEADER, 0`), but still requesting them (`curl_getinfo`)?

Comment: @OverZealous: but its working for other sites like: google.com...

Comment: Seems like `json_decode($data['output'])` returns NULL. Does the website return *valid* JSON data?

Comment: @Salman A: see my function, I am converting the ouptut in json object and then reconverting to normal...

Comment: @vai: seems like you are doing it the other way round: you're first json-decoding the HTML (which is wrong hence *NULL*) and then json-encoding the result.

Comment: yes... i found the problem... i.e. I am storing the data first in an array which is not working...

Answer (score 0):

i remember i get the same result, it outputs the result and i resolve it getting the output buffer:

```
ob_start();
// do the functions
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

good luck

edit:

```
function getUrl($url, $params)
    {
        ob_start();
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }
```

for example i use this function to do a post action

Comment: not working... can you update my load function with your hack and post it here???

Comment: If you're going to do it with output buffering, use `$result = ob_get_clean()` instead of nesting output buffers like that.

Comment: @zital: i hav updated my function according to yours but getting same result...

i.e. `{"err":false,"msg":null}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($data['http_code']!==200)
    exit(json_encode(array('err'=>true, 'msg'=>'Unable to get! Error='.$data['http_code'])));
exit(json_encode(array('err'=>false, 'msg'=>json_encode(utf8_encode($data['output'])))));
```

Comment: you need to parse to utf8 with utf8_encode the result of curl ;)